# Why does Firebase Firestore listener return two callbacks on initial call?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Why for every listener method that I write does the initial callback return the result `twice` as opposed to once? Is it fetching the data twice?

```
func monitorProfiles(updatedAfter: Date, completion: @escaping ([Profile]) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
        self.db.collection("Cities")
            .whereField(DocumentKey.updatedAt.rawValue, isGreaterThan: updatedAfter)
            .addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true, listener: { snapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    Log.error(error)
                } else {
                    guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                        Log.warning(.bee)
                        return
                    }
                    let cameras = snapshot.documents.compactMap { try? $0.data(as: Profile.self) }
                    Log.verbose("Profiles Count: \(profiles.count)") //This fires twice on first execution.
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(profiles)
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you're using a snapshot listener that also returns data only when metadata changes. For example, when you execute a write that modifies data that this listener is observing, the listener will return immediately with a latency-compensated snapshot before the write is executed in the database and then return again (usually rapidly) with the same snapshot after the write has been executed in the database. And this is because the metadata of the first snapshot will show that writes are pending and the metadata of the second snapshot will show that writes are not pending.

Comment: Thanks - removing metadata changes appears to have resolved it and thanks for detailing the logic behind them. It also helped me realize the redundancy in my code where I only wanted to fetch new copies `updatedAfter` a certain date so `includeMetadataChanges` was not necessary in the first place.